# Does HDMI manage backlight?

Tags: hdmi, brightness

I need to manage backlight on a [7 inches touch screen from Chalkboard Electronics](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/7-open-frame-universal-HDMI-LCD-with-capacitive-multi-touch/p/21750207/category=3094861) that has a HDMI connector and a power jack only. I only need to power backlighting on and off. Can it be done through HDMI?

**EDIT**: I found back the real reference from Chalkboard Electronics. The display is based on [this model](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/HSD070PWW1-B00.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brightness adjust can be made through standard USB HID, as stated in the [online documentation](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?p=2144).